# Is the number of finite subgroups of a finite-by-cyclic group finite?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a finite-by-cyclic group, i.e. it contains a finite normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is cyclic.

My question is that: Does $G$ contain only finitely many finite subgroups?

**What I've tried:** Assume that $G/N$ is finite cyclic. Then $G$ is a finite group and then it has only a finite number of subgroups.

Comment: "Assume that $G/N$ is finite cyclic. Then $G$ is a finite group" : why ?

Comment: @Arthur It was a question for the OP... Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Fair enough. I usually address such questions more explicitly to the OP precisely to avoid these misunderstandings. It is impossible for me to know from your original comment whether you want my help or not.

Comment: (Although if you care to look, you will see that just my previous comment on this site is exactly on the opposite side of this issue, speaking of the merits of letting the OP answer the questions in the comments. So I'm not exactly consistent about it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $G$ contains only finitely many finite subgroups. As you pointed out, this is trivial if $G/N$ is finite, so we will consider the case $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $K$ be a finite subgroup of $G$, then $KN$ is also a finite subgroup of $G$ (since $N$ is finite and normal) and therefore $KN/N$ is a finite subgroup of $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$. We conclude that $KN/N = \left\{0\right\}$, hence $KN = N$ and so $K < N$. This means that we have only a finite number of choices for $K$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've learned some good points from it. I appreciate it.